# (Auto-) increment Textfield in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to set a **textfield** (col2) in Django which auto**increments** depending on another columns value (value_column).

The DBtable may shall look like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, value_column
0   , a   , 0   , u
0   , a   , 1   , x
0   , a   , 2   , y
0   , b   , 2   , y
0   , c   , 2   , y
0   , a   , 3   , z
...
1   , Za  , 4   , t
1   , Zb  , 4   , t
...
42  , ZZa , 0   , p
```

What are possible implementations?

Comment: what is the relation between value_column and col2?

Comment: @ruddra if the previous column (col3) has the same value (value_column) for the one to insert, then increment col2. Basically I wonder how to increment letters.